# JackSonMixInAnnotations for Polymorphic Type Handling

Tags: jackson

In following code I am trying to use JackSonMixInAnnotations for  Polymorphic Type Handling
but my code is not working.

Please suggest what changes I need to do, to correct this code.

I am not suppose to make any change in Animal class.Also, like Dog class I may have many classes which  extend Animal class.

Code should print the class of "Animal"(either Dog or Elephant) depending on "type" field of Animal object passed to "test()" in MyController class from client.

Client may send JSON like:

"{\"id\":\"DOG\",\"type\":\"dog\",\"someAttrOfDog\":\"someValue\"}"

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonSubTypes;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonTypeInfo;

@JsonTypeInfo( use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,  include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
/*@JsonSubTypes({// @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Dog.class, name = "dog") 


})*/
public abstract class Animal{

private String id;
private String type;


public String getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getType() {
    return type;
}
public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

}


package com.Animal;

import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonTypeName;

@JsonTypeName("cat")
public class Cat extends Animal{
    String someAttrOfCat;

    public String getSomeAttrOfCat() {
        return someAttrOfCat;
    }

    public void setSomeAttrOfCat(String someAttrOfCat) {
        this.someAttrOfCat = someAttrOfCat;
    }
}




package com.Animal;

import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonTypeName;

@JsonTypeName("dog")
public class Dog extends Animal{

    private String someAttrOfDog;

    public String getSomeAttrOfDog() {
        return someAttrOfDog;
    }

    public void setSomeAttrOfDog(String someAttrOfDog) {
        this.someAttrOfDog = someAttrOfDog;
    }

}

package com.Animal;

import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonSubTypes;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonSubTypes.Type;

@JsonSubTypes (
    { @Type(value = Dog.class, name = "dog") }
    )
public class MixinDog {


}




package com.startUpClasses;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;

import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

import com.Animal.Animal;
import com.Animal.MixinDog;

public class StartApp extends HttpServlet{

    public void init() throws ServletException{ 
    System.out.println("---------In StartApp init------------");
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.getSerializationConfig().addMixInAnnotations(Animal.class, MixinDog.class);
    System.out.println("---------In StartApp init1------------");
    mapper.getDeserializationConfig().addMixInAnnotations(Animal.class, MixinDog.class);
    System.out.println("---------In StartApp init2------------");
    }

}


import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import com.Animal.Animal;

@Controller
public class MyController {


    @RequestMapping( value = "test",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public  @ResponseBody String test(@RequestBody  Animal animal){

        System.out.println("In  Controller");
        System.out.println(animal.getClass());
        return "success";

   }
}
```

AnimalWithJsonType-servlet.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.restcontrollers"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven />
</beans>
```

web.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"       xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>AnimalWithJsonType</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
     <servlet-name>AnimalWithJsonType</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>
          org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
     </servlet-class>
     <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
     </servlet>
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>StartApp</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>com.startUpClasses.StartApp</servlet-class>
   <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
</servlet>  
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>AnimalWithJsonType</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/animals/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: You can use @JsonTypeName annotation to register the type name for the class. Also can you post compilable code? Otherwise it is hard to guess what the problem is.

Comment: You can paste above code in web dynamic project of ecllipse and run it.Add necessary libraries like jackson-all,spring .